# Stripe + Swift architecture arm64 error

Tags: objective-c, swift, linker-errors, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe with Xcode using Swift. I installed the podfile for Stripe and imported `#import "Stripe.h"` to my bridging file. All of other files in the bridge file work fine except Stripe. This is the error that i get when i initialize `Stripe.setDefaultPublishableKey("")`:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Stripe", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for ObjectiveC.Stripe in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_STPPaymentCardTextField", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in STPCheckoutView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_STPAPIClient", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in STPCheckoutView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_STPCard", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in STPCheckoutView.o
  "_StripeDomain", referenced from:
      -[STPCheckoutView createToken:] in STPCheckoutView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @rmaddy do you have the answer?